# How can I sort columns in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I would like to sort a multidimensional array in php like you sort columns in a spreadsheet.
I need to be able to select a start and stop column, and optionally, if the "children" of a column get sorted. I'm not sure how I should explain this properly so I try with an example.

Can I do this with standard PHP functions, or do I need write my own? In case of the latter, I would appreciate some help on now to do it.

```
-------------0------1-------2--- (dimensions)
$someArray[$col1][$col22][$col3];

col1  col2  col3:
a     1     w
c     5     x
b     2     y
d     3     z

unknownSortFunction($someArray, 0, 1, $link=0) // Sort col1 first and then col2 leave col3     (and any "childs") "linked" to column 2.
expected results:
col1  col2  col3
a     1     w
b     2     y
c     3     z
d     5     x
```

Optionally I would like to be able to sort without keeping col3 "linked" to col2, ex:

```
col1  col2  col3
a     1     w
b     2     x
c     3     y
d     5     z
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.uasort.php

Comment: When you say "like you sort columns in a spreadsheet", I would expect to see a data structure that is more like $somearray[$row][$col] = $data. I only ask this because the examples are so vague, but does your specific application require a 3D array? If so can you give an example of what data you are representing? Maybe you could still use a 2D and have a simpler sorting solution? Just wondering...

Comment: A little unclear: why do you use 3-dimensional array for 2D table?

Comment: @Justin: My application actually uses a 4D array. Long story short: Simplest approach to gather the same data on different "levels" except from the sorting issues ;)

Comment: You have forgotten to add to your question how to actually retrieve or set a value in that `$somearray`. How to specify the row for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-dimensions arrays sort is resolved by this function in php:

```
Array Multisort:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php
```

As advanced tip, you can extend its using by setting witch dimensions you want to sort, leaving the other out. Using the output more as a index to search your data.

The manual can provide enough info to try out this function on our needs. But, if this is not the result you expect, instead you need to create your own sorting method of sorting. Then you can use the:

```
Usort:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php
```

Witch let you create your own method of sorting. You can even extend the multi sort this way.